# Angular 4 - Need assistance for better architecture

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a query regarding Angular 4 project architecture.

I want to build an application which will have below sub-modules

1. Account Module - Login Page, Forgot Password Page etc.
2. Admin Module -  This will have admin related stuff.
3. Public Module - This module will be exposed to end users.

Now, I have two approaches in my mind

1. Keep only single module i.e. AppModule and create 3 main components for respective modules as mentioned above. Then create more components and inject those components inside these main components. Use Angular Router module to manage routing.
2. Second way, to create 3 different modules for each application as shown in below picture. But in this case, we will have to create a separate module as well which will be shared across all these 3 modules. That module will contain all services. But by doing this, we will have multiple modules in our project.

[image]

I am not sure which approach is correct. Can someone guide me here & provide me suggestions for better architecture.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" way in terms of architecture.  Both options 1 and 2 are valid ways of organizing your project; however, I would prefer to use option 2, particularly if you think your project will end up being medium to large sized.  By having separate modules, you can implement other beneficial features to help improve performance, such as lazy-loading.

I personally use 1. a Core module for all main pages such as Home, About, etc., 2. a Shared module for all components (eg. `<app-navbar></app-navbar>`), and 3. a Routing module for the router.

You can check out an example project that I made using this organizational structure here:
https://github.com/stanleyeosakul/bulma-publishing

Answer (score 1):

I personally would like to go with 2nd approach. That is to create separate modules for each of the features.

Account Module - Login Page, Forgot Password Page etc.

Admin Module - This will have admin related stuff.

Public Module - This module will be exposed to end users.

Then to extract all the common logic and functionality in shared module where you will either create service/pip/components for each common logic.

The benefit is you can always reuse the common logic as well as you can override or create your custom modules as you need without affecting your core services.

Can you share your thoughts?